# Using binomial expansion to evaluate $\sqrt{104}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

> **Question**:Use binomial expansion to evaluate $\sqrt{104}$

The answer should be $10.1980$

I understand that I have to get it to the form $(n+x)^{1/2}$ but I'm not sure how to.

I have completed a similar question but with $\sqrt{0.96}$, in which I worked out $x=-0.04$ and went on to show solution, but $x$ is not $103$ in this question.

Comment: Maybe you can use the same method you used for $\sqrt{0.96}$, but you'd need to "reduce" $104$ to a much smaller number.

Comment: First step is to write this as $$10\cdot \sqrt{1.04}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{104} = 10\left(1+\frac{4}{100}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net you should probably post that as an answer

Comment: @sai-kartik I find comments quite useful in such situations. Not every question needs to be actually answered. Sometimes a few hints in comments do the job as well.

Comment: @Peter Thank you! That hint was all I needed.

Comment: @Peter fair enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the binomial expansion, $\sqrt{1+h} \approx 1+\frac{h}{2}-\frac{h^2}{8}$ for small $h$. Therefore
$$
\sqrt{104}=10\sqrt{1+0.04} \approx 1+\frac{0.04}{2}-\frac{0.04^2}{8} = 10.1980
$$